# An interesting set of integer degrees

Tags: number-theory

For analytical calculations in astronomy are extremely important sets of numbers $\left\{A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n\right\}$ such that:
$$
\sum\limits_k {A_K} = -2.5 \ln \left(\sum\limits_k { 10^{-0.4*A_k} } \right)/ \ln(10). 
$$
It is easy to show that the task of finding such sets is to find numbers whose product and sum are equal.

So, the question is: is there a set of integer powers of $10^{0.4}$ such that their product is equal to their sum?

Comment: Please use the right formatting for formulas and in the future choose a title that is more directly linked to your actual question (The last sentence).

Comment: should it not be " ..set of integer powers of $10^{-0.4}$.." ?

Comment: The question is about integer degrees, so I don't think "${10^{0.4}}$ or ${10^{-0.4}}$?" matters.

Comment: From $c=10^{0.4}>2$ it follows that the sum of all powers $c^i$ up to and including $c^n$ is less than $2 c^n$, which in turn is less than $c^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a finite set of numbers $A_k$ satisfying your condition. First of all, let me reformulate the condition.

$$\prod_k 10^{-0,4 \ A_k} = \sum_k 10^{- 0,4 \ A_k}$$

An example is given by
\begin{align}
A_1=A_2 = -5; \quad A_3 = \dots = A_{9802}=0.
\end{align}
 Then
$$\prod_{k=1}^{9802} 10^{-0,4 \ A_k} = 100 \times 100 = 10000$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{9802} 10^{- 0,4 \ A_k} = 100+100+9800= 10000$$